# How to set tag for fragments in Navigation Component Architecture

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

recently I started using Navigation Component Architecture, now there's a problem I have. in previous fragment transactions we could set tag while transacting to another fragment, how can we do that while using Navigation Component Architecture.

Comment: why you have to set tag, maybe there's another solution for that. I'm saying becasue i didn't find any method to get fragment by tag in Navigations.

Comment: @HussnainHaidar well I use tag to determined that this fragment is added from which activity.

Comment: @SinaMN75 I am also facing the same problem, did you come up with something or any workaround? Basically, I need to call a particular function on a particular fragment. If there is something like finding fragment by tag or name, it will solve the purpose

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. If anyone finds a solution to this I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Another one with same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Based on [FragmentNavigator](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/navigation/navigation-fragment/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/fragment/FragmentNavigator.kt) source-code the target fragment will be instantiate without any option to assigning a tag. So you can't.

But you mentions in comments that:

> I use tag to determined that this fragment is added from which activity.

You can use

```
findNavController().previousBackStackEntry
```

to get previous stack (who opened this screen) information like its `id`, `argument`, `destination.label`, `destination.id` and so on.