# How to access the host fragment from ViewPager page fragment using Navigation Architecture Components

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-navigation

I've a project that I want to migrate to [Navigation Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started).

Before the migration, I have an activity that has a fragment that hosts a `ViewPager`; and I can access a method in this fragment from the `ViewPager` adapter fragment by referencing the host fragment tag that I had set in the fragment transaction:

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment ) ((MyActivity) requireActivity())
        .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_tag"); 
fragment.someMethodInMyFragment();
```

Here is a diagram that deceits a part of the migration, and what I need to access through the yellow arrow:

[image]

In Navigation components, I didn't find a chance [to set a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801487/how-to-set-tag-for-fragments-in-navigation-component-architecture) to the destination fragment that hosts the `ViewPager`, so that I can access it through the tag like before. Also, the `ViewPager` adapter fragments are not a part of the Navigation components.

What I have tried: **In the `ViewPager` adapter fragment:**

Attempt 1

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getParentFragment(); // This returns the navigation host fragment. So ClassCastException is raised
fragment.someMethodInMyFragment();
```

Attempt 2

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
     .findFragmentById(R.id.myFragment); // id of myFragment in the nav graph.
fragment.someMethodInMyFragment(); // fragment is null
```

UPDATE:

posting `ViewPager` adapter

```
public class PageFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public PageFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return MyPagerFragment.newInstance(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

}
```

And I setup the ViewPager in `MyFragment` like below

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        PageFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new PageFragmentPagerAdapter(requireActivity()
                                                   .getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing any of this and not just passing your `Fragment` to your adapter directly? You control the constructor for your adapter and can pass it whatever you want.

Comment: @ianhanniballake So, I need to pass `MyFragment` as the adapter argument, and then pass it to the adapter's fragment through `getItem()` .. I will try this out .. sorry if I didn't get you much. I posted the adapter, and fragment code if that make it clearer .. Thank you

Comment: Why are you passing `requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()` (which is always the correct thing to pass in)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` as the `FragmentManager` for your adapter.

Instead, you should always use `getChildFragmentManager()` for Fragments that are fully contained within another fragment - you'll note that under configuration changes or process death and recreation, this is required to restore the state of each Fragment correctly.

When you use the child FragmentManager, then `requireParentFragment()` will return the correct fragment that you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for that, unfortunately that raised NPE when I tried `getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFragment)` for the returned fragment ..

Comment: Like my answer said, you'd just use `requireParentFragment()` from within one of your ViewPager fragments (as that's the parent now that you set it up with the parent's child FragmentManager)

Comment: it's now `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment PagerFragment{3a76a43} (73d6dd69-0f1a-4428-8c8e-055a24fe61ae) id=0x7f0800f8} is not a child Fragment, it is directly attached to com.xx.MainActivity@e045857`

Comment: Then you haven't changed your adapter to use `getChildFragmentManager()`.